# How to add pattern to existing image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to add a pattern from one image onto a section of another. For example, in the image below I want to make just the tail have the pattern below

[image]

[image]

Comment: you mean that the blue image must be insert in the image c shape

Comment: yes blue pattern should replace the grey color on the c shape

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Pattern feature.  Just save your blue image as a pattern (Edit > Define Pattern), then fill your C with it...

[image: pattern]

Even better: allow greater control using layer mask!

[image: pattern2]

Answer (score 0):

Open both the image side by side
Active the C image
Click the Magic Wand tool (Press W)
Go to Layer panel
Hold Ctrl and click on the thumbnail

[image]

Click on the other image (Blue)
Select All > Copy 
Click on the 1st image (C image)
Go to Edit > Paste Into (shift+ctrl+V)
And Adjust the image to fit in the shape

[image]